# create_ap wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver

Tags: kernel, driver, raspberry-pi4, hotspot, access-point

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4, and I'm experiencing issues with the 'create_ap' command.
`create_ap -g <ip> --no-virt  wlan0 wwan0 name pass`sud

```
sudo create_ap -g 100.104.158.255 --no-virt wlan0 wwan0 trudi 12345678
WARN: brmfmac driver doesn't work properly with virtual interfaces and
      it can cause kernel panic. For this reason we disallow virtual
      interfaces for your adapter.
      For more info: https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/203
Config dir: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.B95gg0aT
PID: 2093
Sharing Internet using method: nat
hostapd command-line interface: hostapd_cli -p /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.B95gg0aT/hostapd_ctrl
WARN: Low entropy detected. We recommend you to install `haveged'
Configuration file: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.B95gg0aT/hostapd.conf
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr d8:3a:dd:65:bb:2f and ssid "trudi"
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan0: AP-ENABLED
```

I've always used this command, but for two days now, it creates the hotspot, but when I try to connect with another device, it suddenly disappears without giving me any specific error in the log, and it gives me this error:
`wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver`
I don't know how to solve this issue. Has anyone experienced the same problem?

I have tried various alternatives without specifying the IP or using -w 2, but nothing works. I have also tried rebooting the system and updating all packages, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: `create_ap` project doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, but readme mentions two other projects which my be worth taking a look https://github.com/oblique/create_ap?tab=readme-ov-file#forks-and-continuation-of-this-project